# Mimic Android Lifecyle in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I've been accustomed to the Android lifecycle with onCreate, onResume, onPause, onDestroy. This seems to be similar to the UIKit lifecycle. However, I am using the SwiftUI lifecycle which doesn't seem to have these methods out of the box. I've been trying to mimic the Android lifecycle with SwiftUI with the below code. However, I've noticed some different behaviors than what I desire. How can I get to the expected behavior?

Observed behavior

- onDestroy is called when **user navigates to next page** & when view is popped off stack
- onPause is called when user goes to home screen or goes to another app or screen is turned off

  - **all views in stack under current view onPause are also called**
- onResume is called after onCreate or user comes back to app

  - **ContentView onResume is not called when view is returned to after next view was popped off stack**
- onCreate is triggered when view is shown for the first time

Expected behavior

- onDestroy is called when view is popped off stack
- onPause is called when user goes to home screen or goes to another app or screen is turned off
- onResume is called after onCreate or user comes back to app **or when view is returned to after next view was popped off stack**
- onCreate is triggered when view is shown for the first time

```
.onAppear {
    if !viewCreated {
        viewCreated = true
        
        print("view2: on create")
    }

    print("view2: on resume")
}
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
    print("view2: on resume")
}
.onDisappear {
    print("view2: on destroy")
}
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
    print("view2: on pause")
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to your question. Your observations of the lifecycle and expectations are the same with minor nuances, can you provide a more specific, singular, example?

Comment: The minor nuances you see are exactly what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: You really need to chance the slight nuances in your mental model. Otherwise you will find debugging to be nearly impossible. As a case in point, with your `.onAppear()` code, that view was most likely created LONG before `.onAppear()` was ever called. If your assumption is that the code you want to run in `.onAppear()` runs upon creation of the view, then you would be introducing one or more bugs. SwiftUI can, and often does, create its views very early, and they hang around if needed. You need to learn SwiftUI's paradigm if you want to program with it.